# Why i am unable to fetch the values of selected options in jquery on click of option?

Tags: jquery, node.js, drop-down-menu

I have the following select menu with options.

```
 <select name="assigneeSelect" id="{{this.commonID}}" class="custom-select sources" key="{{this.id}}" placeholder="{{this.assignee}}">
    <option value="5f4a31eb75d1ab1668d11765">Charlotte Miles</option>
    <option value="d91c3fb7642c6d415880301e1c776df4">Sulekha Yadav</option>
    <option value="5f4d49636dba221200f2cc1f">Adele Armstrong</option>
  </select>
```

So in jQuery I am wrapping this code with more classes as follows since I have more than one select menu option on the same page.

```
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
    id      = $(this).attr("id"),
    name    = $(this).attr("name");

var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
    template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
    template += '<div class="custom-options">';
    $(this).find("option").each(function() {
      template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
    });
template += '</div></div>';

$(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
$(this).hide();
$(this).after(template);
});

$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
$(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
$(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});

$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
$('html').one('click',function() {
  $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
});

$(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

So I am retrieving the selected text on click of option in select menu. I don't want to retrieve it onChange of selected menu as I have to call one AJAX Get on click. means after selecting one of thee options from select dropdown.

```
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {


**var text = $(this).text();**
**var val = $(this).val();**

alert("id ="+id+" text = "+text+" val ="+val);

})
```

But here in val i am not getting the option's value although i am getting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `custom-option` using:

```
<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>'
```

this doesn't have a "value" that jquery can extract using `.val()`, but it does have `data-value=..`.

You can get the data-value using

```
var val = $(this).data("value");
```